# How to get sum of divisors in my program?

Tags: python

In my program, it is supposed to ask the user for a number, then displays all the divisors possible, but in the end, it has to display the sum of all the divisors. I'm having trouble with the last part and would appreciate some help.

My code:

```
    prompt = int(input("Enter an interger: "))

print("The divisors of the integer you entered are: ")
for i in range(1, prompt+1):
    if(prompt%i==0):
        print(i)
        print(f")
```

Example if user inputed 20:

```
The divisors of the integer you entered are:

1

2

4

5

10

20

The sum of the divisors is: 42
```

Comment: The code has a syntax error. Try to simply copy and paste it (properly formatted) into the question.

Comment: Oops, sorry guys was trying to put an f string into the print was not finished. But I got the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This topic is also discussed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686862/having-trouble-filling-in-empty-function-so-it-returns-the-sum-of-all-divisors/61687482#61687482

Answer (score 4):

Just a simple modification of your code can do the trick. like:

```
prompt = int(input("Enter an interger: "))

print("The divisors of the integer you entered are: ")
divisor_sum = 0 #updated line
for i in range(1, prompt+1):
    if(prompt%i==0):
        print(i)
        divisor_sum+=i #calculate sum of all divisors

print("The sum of divisors " + str(divisor_sum)) #print the sum of divisors
```

Also you can use `list comprehension` to make your program shorter and smarter, like:

```
prompt = int(input("Enter an interger: "))

divisors = [i for i in range(1,prompt+1) if prompt%i==0]
divisor_sum = sum(divisors)

print("The divisors of the integer you entered are: ")
for i in divisors:
    print(i)

print("The sum of divisors " + str(divisor_sum))
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need a variable to store the sum. I have used `s`. Rest all code is perfectly fine except `print(f")`. It is unused and gives syntax error due to incomplete `"`. Moreover, `f` is not defined

```
prompt = int(input("Enter an interger: "))
s=0
print("The divisors of the integer you entered are: ")

for i in range(1, prompt+1):
    if(prompt%i==0):
        s += i
        print(i)
print ("The sum of the divisors is: %d" %s)
```

**Output**

```
Enter an interger: 20
The divisors of the integer you entered are: 
1
2
4
5
10
20
The sum of the divisors is: 42
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, This question reminded me about a question i solved in project Euler ,and i did it in O(sqrt(n)) complexity .

if you consider 9 ,

We dont need to consider till 9 to get all factors . We just need to consider till 3 if we have X as divisor then prompt/X is also a divisor . With this property you could make the algorithm more efficient

```
import time
from math import sqrt
prompt = int(input("Enter an interger: "))
start =time.time()
print("The divisors of the integer you entered are: ")

sumofdivisors=0 
for divisor in range(1, int(sqrt(prompt))+1):
    if(prompt%divisor==0):
        sumofdivisors+=divisor
        sumofdivisors+=(prompt/divisor)
        if (divisor==prompt/divisor):
            sumofdivisors-=divisor
            print(divisor)
        else:
            print(divisor)
            print(prompt/divisor)
print("sum is",sumofdivisors)
end=time.time()
print("time taken is",end-start)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter an interger: 8
The divisors of the integer you entered are: 
1
8.0
2
4.0
sum is 15.0
time took =  0.0002665519714355469
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is storing the list of valid divisors in a container of some sorts. In this case the appropriate "container" is a list.
This has the advantage that you store the divisors for later use.

```
prompt = int(input("Enter an interger: "))
divisors = []
print("The divisors of the integer you entered are: ")

for i in range(1, prompt+1):
    if(prompt%i==0):
        print(i)
        divisors.append(i)

print("The sum of divisors " + sum(divisors)) #print the sum of divisors
# max(divisors)
# min(divisors)
# etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prompt = int(input("Enter an interger: "))

print("The divisors of the integer you entered are: ")
total= 0
for i in range(1, prompt+1):
    if(prompt%i==0):
        print(i)
        total+= i

print("The sum of the divisors is:{}".format(total))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter an interger: 20
The divisors of the integer you entered are: 
1
2
4
5
10
20
The sum of the divisors is:42
```

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking, when you are summing the divisors of a number you do not include the number in question. the +1 normally added the range function is not needed, and will produce in incorrect result.
The following Wikipedia article on amicable pairs can be used as a reference.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).