# How to find the sum of all the divisors of a number, without including it

Tags: python

Finding the sum of all the divisors of a number, without including that particular number that is being divided.

For example if we want to find the divisors of number 6 they would be 1,2,3. Number 6 should be included as it is a divisor, but for this scenario we are not considering it.

Note:- number 3 and 4 are not included since, when you divide number 6 by number 3, there would be a remainder.

A divisor is a number that divides into another without a remainder.

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum =  0
    # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
    return sum

print(sum_divisors(0)) # 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1 # 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18 # 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51 # 114
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592953/how-to-get-sum-of-divisors-in-my-program

Comment: Put `[python] sum of divisors` into the SO search box and you'll find lots of examples you can copy from. But if you want to learn to program, you should try to figure it out yourself. Would you go to IKEA if you were trying to learn how to be a carpenter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combined filter() and lambda() function

```py
num = 36
div_sum = sum(list(filter(lambda div : num % div == 0 , range(1, num))))

# divisors :  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18]
# divisors sum :  55 

print('divisors sum : ', div_sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it:

```py
def sum_divisors(n):
    return sum([i for i in range(1, n)
                if n % i == 0])

print(sum_divisors(0))
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18
print(sum_divisors(102)) # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51
```

Output

```
0
1
55
114
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to find the divisors of the number first, and then sum them. Finding out if a number is a divisor of another number is pretty simple:

```
if x % y == 0:
  is_divisor = True
```

Modulo - % - returns the remainder of a division. 9 % 2 = 1. 10 % 3 = 1. However, we'll need to know which numbers to check. We could just loop through every number up to our input:

```
for i in range(n):
  if n % i == 0:
    is_divisor = True
```

...but that's too much. For example, we know that the highest possible divisor of n that isn't n itself, is 1/2n if n is even, and lower if it's not. Instead, let's focus on getting each pair, and then check if we should continue. We also need to store all of these numbers, so lets create some lists:

```
lower_divisors = []
upper_divisors = []
```

We'll want to know what our current highest lower divisor and lowest highest divisor are, and also know where to start. We can populate the lower divisor list with 1 and the highest with n. We can worry about removing n later.

```
lower_divisors = [1]
upper_divisors = [n]

continu = True

while continu:
  # Let's get the last item in each list
  highest_low = lower_divisors[-1]
  lowest_high = upper_divisors[-1]

  for i in range(highest_low + 1, lowest_high):
    if n % i == 0:
      lower_divisors.append(i)
      upper_divisors.append(n // i)
      break
  continu = False

# If we've left the loop, we have all of our divisors.
lower_sum = sum(lower_divisors)
higher_sum = sum(upper_divisors) - n   #Gotta take it back out!
sm = lower_sum + higher_sum
return sm
```

That should be a fast way to achieve your goal, without making your computer work harder - but... it's a lot more steps to write. I wrote it in far more steps to make it clear what I was doing and to be readable, but it could definitely be trimmed up a lot.

Upon running the code, the simple method of looping through each number from 1 to n starts to really add up when n is over 8 digits. 9 digit numbers were taking around 12-16 seconds on my machine. The longer approach above returns 32-digit values for n in under 1/10th of a second.