# What is going wrong in this sum divisors program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

function should return the sum of all the divisors of a number, without including it. A divisor is a number that divides into another without a remainder. so for this I have written below function in python.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
     k = 1
     sum = 0
     while k < n :
       
       if n % int(k) == 0:
        print(k)    
        sum = sum + int(k)
        k += 1
       k = k + 1 
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
     return sum


print(sum_divisors(0))  # 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1  # total 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) 
print("----------")  # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18  # total 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) 
print("----------") # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51 # total 114

But I am getting o/p as --> 0 , 1 49, 112 respectively for above function.

after analysis I found that - value of "k" is not getting incremented inside if block as 2 and 4.
K value is comming as below for above four functioned when getting called-->

0
----------
1
1    --> it should be 2 
----------
1    --> after 1 next should come as 2 , as 36 is divisible by 2
3    -->  after 3 next should come as 4 , as 36 is divisible by 4, but it is missing
6
9
12
18
49
----------
1  --> after 1 next should come as 2 , as 102 is divisible by 2
3  
6
17
34
51
112
```

so can anyone please tell what is going wrong above. If possible you can suggest any alternate method to optimize above program.

Comment: Any reason why this is written so complicated (homework maybe)? You can use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. And if you use `for` you'll see that you can use the `sum` function with a generator and it boils down to one line of code: `return sum(i for i in range(1, n) if n % i == 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of all the divisors of a number, without including it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61686862/how-to-find-the-sum-of-all-the-divisors-of-a-number-without-including-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're incrementing `k` twice, once conditionally inside the `if`, once unconditionally outside it, so you can never find adjacent factors. Remove the one inside the `if`.

Better, just replace it with a `for`+`range` loop and stop managing `k` manually:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    sum = 0
    for k in range(1, n):
        if n % k == 0:  # No need to int-ify k, it's always an int anyway
            print(k)    
            sum += k    # Can use += to avoid repetition, and k is an int already

    # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
    return sum
```

If the `print` is purely for debugging and can be removed, this simplifies to a one-liner, with the optimized `sum` function + a generator expression:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
    return sum(k for k in range(1, n) if n % k == 0)
```

Comment: @DanielHao: I say that so often I get tired of saying it. In this particular case at least, it's harmless enough (they weren't doing it in global scope, and they were clearly writing their loop in place of `sum`, so they didn't actually need the built-in). *shrugs*

Comment: thanks for you answer and optimisation of code. Yes it helped.

Answer (score 1):

you only have to comment the first addition of k :

it is as if you're incrementing it twice so you're jumping on numbers to test on.

```
def sum_divisors(n):
     k = 1
     sum = 0
     while k < n :
       
       if n % int(k) == 0:
        # print(k)    
        sum = sum + int(k)
        # k += 1
       k = k + 1 
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
     return sum


print(sum_divisors(0))  # 0
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1  # total 1
print(sum_divisors(36)) 
print("----------")  # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18  # total 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) 
print("----------") # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51 # total 114
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing it out, later on I noticed no need to increment it inside if loop if it is getting divided, better I should come out of loop and just increase there so that condition of while loop can also be cheked simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You have both `k += 1` and `k = k + 1` inside your loop, so that means that you add 2 for every iteration.

This code:

```
def sum_divisors(n):
k = 1
sum = 0
while k < n :
    if n % int(k) == 0:
        print(k)    
        sum = sum + int(k)

    k = k + 1 
  # Return the sum of all divisors of n, not including n
    return sum


print(sum_divisors(0))  # 0
print("----------") 
print(sum_divisors(3)) # Should sum of 1  # total 1
print("----------") 
print(sum_divisors(36)) 
print("----------")  # Should sum of 1+2+3+4+6+9+12+18  # total 55
print(sum_divisors(102)) 
print("----------") # Should be sum of 2+3+6+17+34+51 # total 114
```

Gives this output:

```
0
----------
1
1
----------
1
2
3
4
6
9
12
18
55
----------
1
2
3
6
17
34
51
114
----------
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "else" for k = k + 1

```
def sum_divisors(n):
k = 1
sum = 0
print(n)
while k < n :
    if n % k == 0:
        print(k)    
        sum = sum + k
        k += 1
    else:
        k = k + 1 
return sum
```

[image]